# Android gradle skip build before running test?

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-testing

I would like to skip the build process and directly run tests when I do

```
./gradlew connectedDevDebug
```

I could also use adb command but it will run test on only one deivce at a time.

Comment: Why will you want to skip Build, how can you get the apk then? Gradle will skip the Build if there is no changes by default.

Comment: The debug and debugAndroidTest apk is already installed using ./gradlew iDD iDDAT. I just want to re-run the tests (no code changed). But when I do ./gradlew cDDAT, it takes a lot time compared to using adb command. This is a partial output,

:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDevDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDevDebugManifest
:app:preDevReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preProdDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preProdReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
...
:app:packageDevDebugAndroidTest
:app:assembleDevDebugAndroidTest
:app:installDevDebug
...

Comment: looks like all the build tasks are UP-TO-DATE and only app:checkDevDebugManifest re-run. how long does it take? I don't think you can skip those steps if you run cAT unless you create your own gradle tasks that only executes the adb commands.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is currently no `gradle` tasks that just runs the tests.

But once you have installed (and run) the tests, you can (re-)run them directly with the `am instrument` command. To start them from your development machine's command line just run:

```
adb shell am instrument -w <test_package_name>/<runner_class>
```

You can copy the actual command from AndroidStudio's output. Just run the tests from AndroidStudio, and then scroll to the top of the test log view.

There is one caveat, `am instrument` does not create any test-reports. All test results are written to `stdout`. However you could pipe `stdout` into a file and create a report yourself. I.e. [this tool](https://github.com/dpreussler/automator-log-converter) can create an xml JUnit test report from the output of `am instrument`.

If you have made changes to the tests you can rebuild and install them with:

```
./gradlew installDebugAndroidTest
```

For detailed information and instructions about starting tests from the command line you can refer to the official article [Test from the Command Line](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/command-line.html#RunTestsDevice)